# Why does print(sys.modules['__main__']) in bar.py produces the same output?

Tags: python, import, module, sys

```
#foo.py
import bar
import sys
print(sys.modules['__main__'])
```

```
#bar.py
import foo
import sys
print(sys.modules['__main__'])
```

When foo.py was run, the output was the following:

[image: Output]

So why does `print(sys.modules['__main__'])` in `bar.py` produces the same output? Can someone please explain to me how did the execution take place?

Comment: `sys.modules['__main__']` is always the module that was run directly by python (as opposed to imported). In your case that is always `foo.py`

Comment: @rdas Hey, but how does ```'__main__'``` is accessed from ```bar.py```? And is a new object created for ```sys``` in ```bar.py``` or it's the same object created for ```foo.py```?

Comment: There is only one `sys` module - and hence only one `sys.module` dictionary

Comment: @rdas Oh!! So that ```import sys``` in ```bar.py``` just creates a reference to ```sys``` module in ```foo.py```, right?

Comment: Not exactly, they just both import the same thing. No one module "owns" the sys module. It's maintained by the python runtime.

Comment: @rdas If they both import, then how do they produce the same output and also one ```sys.module``` dictionary?

Comment: What do you mean "they produce the same output"?

Comment: @rdas By that, I was talking about ```sys.modules['__main__']``` producing the same output in ```foo.py``` as well as ```bar.py```.

Comment: Because it's the same thing that's producing the output. When foo imports sys and gets `sys.modules['__main__']` it gets `foo.py` since it's the main file being run. When the bar module is imported & run it also imports the sys module - which is the same thing that foo imported and gets the same output. There are never multiple copies of __any__ module loaded into the runtime.

Comment: @rdas Ahh!!! Thank you so much. I was stuck with that for 3 hours. You are extremely good at elucidating.